# Changing the emailid associated with your android account

Tags: google-account, 9.0-pie, lg

My android phone is LG W10 Alpha LMX210LMW running Android 9. I have a particular email account associated with the phone say emailid1@gmail.com - I don't use that email id at all - it's solely for the phone. I wish to delete this emailid permanently. But then it would be a problem for my phone.

I tried this to change the id - but like it says it's not usually allowed for gmail ids.

So is there a way I can backup the phone related info (like phone contacts, apps installed & other stuff) & delete the account & reconfigure it with a new gmail id - say emaild2@gmail.com

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You can copy all contacts using the web UI: https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/1069522?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en open section `From a Gmail account`

Comment: contacts backup sync with PC [MyPhoneExplorer](https://www.fjsoft.at/en) remove google account [wikihow.com](https://www.wikihow.com/Remove-a-Google-Account-on-Android)

Comment: What do you see in Settings>Accounts and Settings>Google

Comment: @Aayush - I see my emaild

Comment: First of all make sure you have two or more accounts already logged in. Go to Settings>Accounts>Google>(click on your email id)>tap on three dots on top right corner>tap on remove account

Comment: @Aayush - but if all the data (like contacts, apps installed, settings etc) is stored in the first account, then won't all that data be erased when I remove the first acct?

Comment: Take a look at this... https://gadgets.ndtv.com/internet/features/new-gmail-account-switch-migrate-1682770 and tell if it works for you. I'll post the answer

Comment: @Aayush - this link seems to be about how to move your emails & email contacts to another email acct. What I want is move all phone related stuff into the new acct.

Comment: Okay so after an hour, i have answers. https://www.vaultme.com/articles/how-to-change-gmail-address The option 3 is you i guess. I searched and found that there is no way to transfer your app purchases to another phone except for Google Play’s new Family Library

Comment: Is your phone rooted?

Comment: @Sruly - no, it's not.